# Ubuntu set default login desktop

Tags: gnome, 20.04, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome

I've installed `ubuntu-dekstop-minimal` on 20.04 and I'd like to make the "Ubuntu" session the default (as opposed to "GNOME on Xorg").

As this is being provisioned by Vagrant, I'd like to be able to do this by command rather than using the cog icon. Any ideas?

Here's an image of what I see at the login screen, note GNOME on Xorg is default, I want to make Ubuntu the default:

[image: screenshot of login screen]

Comment: After you log in to Ubuntu, doesn't that stay selected for the next login? It does on mine, but I use lightdm.

Comment: @OrganicMarble yeah it does stay the default which is a first step. However, I'd like to set this default ahead of time with a bash command if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to edit the file `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/<username-of-Vagrant>` and change the valid session name under `XSession=` line.

```
[User]
Language=
Session=
XSession=gnome-xorg
Icon=/home/admin/.face
SystemAccount=false
```

you can use command line tools to change the line `XSession=`

Be-careful with the name of the session, the text shown on the gdm screen is not the actual session name. You need to look in for the files in `/usr/share/xsessions/` and/or (based on session x or Wayland) `/usr/share/wayland/`

**Warning**: wrong edit will result not able to login.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me `sudo sed -i 's/XSession=gnome-xorg/XSession=ubuntu.desktop/g' /var/lib/AccountsService/users/vagrant`